# How to check if number is harmonic divisor or not

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, integers, harmonic-numbers, perfect-numbers

I need to write a program which checks if the given number is harmonic divisor or not. So I search on the internet and found a definition of it but couldn't understand really what is harmonic divisor.

This is what I found : https://archive.lib.msu.edu/crcmath/math/math/h/h085.htm

There is some functions in the given link. d() and something like q() (I couldn't type that char). I don't know what this functions are.

Thanks for any help or explanation.

(note: I don't know if sharing link is allowed on this site. If it is not allowed please warn me. I will edit the question.)

Comment: Surely whatever exercise you got defined what a harmonic divisor is?

Comment: Try Wikipedia [harmonic divisor number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_divisor_number) instead of MathWorld. The article has examples.

Comment: @Somos thanks this one is much understandable

Comment: @Somos:  I think your comment qualifies as an answer to the OP's question, in as much as he confirms that "[it] is much [more] understandable", likewise, in the spirit of not leaving questions in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The harmonic divisor numbers are [OEIS sequence A001599](https://oeis.org/A001599)
$$   1, 6, 28, 140, 270, 496, 672, 1638, 2970, 6200, 8128, 8190,\dots $$
The Wikipedia article [Harmonic divisor number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_divisor_number) states:

> In mathematics, a harmonic divisor number, [...], is a positive integer whose divisors have a harmonic mean that is an integer.

It also states:

> The harmonic mean $\,H(n)\,$ of the divisors of any number $\,n\,$ can be expressed as the formula
> $$ H(n) = \frac{n\,\sigma_0(n)}{\sigma_1(n)} $$
> where $\,\sigma_i(n)\,$ is the sum of the $i$th powers of the divisors of
> $\,n:\sigma_0\,$ is the number of divisors, and $\,\sigma_1\,$ is the sum
> of the divisors (Cohen 1997).

and this:

> $$ H(4) = \frac{3}{1+\frac12+\frac14} = 12/7, $$
> $$ H(5) = \frac{2}{1+\frac15} = 5/3, $$
> $$ H(7) = \frac{2}{1+\frac17} = 7/4, $$
> and $$ H(140) = H(4\cdot 5\cdot 7) = H(4)\cdot H(5)\cdot H(7)
>  = \frac{12}7 \cdot \frac53 \cdot \frac74 = 5. $$